# How to increase ajax asynchronous postback speed - asp.net

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, postback, performance

I am developing a web based mmorpg. so speed is very vital for me since people don't like slow games :)

i have a map system which uses ajax and asynchronous postbacks for walking. so i want to make it faster as much as possible.

if anybody can spend some time at my page and make suggestion for me i appreciate that.

using windows server 2008 r2 - compression enabled at iis

iis 7.5

netframework 3.5

asp.net 2.0

microsoft visual studio 2008 sp1 c#

my game register page : http://www.pokemoncraft.com/register.aspx

free to register do not require email activation

the page i want you to test if possible for you : http://www.pokemoncraft.com/gamepage.aspx

also i am open to every kind of general asp.net ajax performance suggestion

Comment: This question seems a bit too open-ended IMO... Consider providing code samples or something more specific than "How can I make it faster?". Also, you're not likely to get much input from SO users unless you either disable mandatory registration, or give a default login that we can use.

Comment: Why use postback then. Just write your javascript code yourself to do the ajax calls.

Comment: @James Black has the right idea. ASP.NET Webforms PostBack model is an extremely heavy solution to providing asynchronous content. If speed is an issue, chances are you'll want to build your own AJAX model that doesn't use ViewState.

Comment: interesting point of view but how can i write my own ajax postback. i am using asp.net update panel for this.

Comment: You stop using the asp.net update panel, that's the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Cache the results on the server
2. do callbacks to pull more data in the background even when the user does nothing (cache some data in the browser)
3. don't return heavy formats like xml ... just return raw data.
4. use css instead of inline styles (this should response lengths)
5. strip out white space where possible in the reponse to reduce the needed bandwidth.

... the list is endless ...

I could do this all day lol :)